# Does razorpay charge additional fees for sms and email notification service through upi payment link integration

Tags: reactjs, payment-gateway, razorpay, web-deployment-project, upi

In my app, I integrated the rzorpay upi payment link generating api. The payment link is sent to the consumer by email and SMS since it is functioning properly.I'm curious as to whether there are any additional costs associated with the SMS and email services that Razorpay offers.

I went through the docs and could'nt find any information regarding fees other than the 2% charged per transaction.If anyone knows anything about this please responde